# OSX Script execution error -10810 in mac

Tags: java, ios, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run an OSX script to bring the browser to front for selenium execution, but failing due to below error.

```
javax.script.ScriptException: An error of type -10810 has occurred.
oasscript errorAn error of type -10810 has occurred.
```

Below is the code which I am using to run the script.

```
public void bringBrowserToFront() {
    try {
        String script = "tell app \"Google chrome\" to activate";
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
        engine.eval(script);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println("oasscript error" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Could some one please let me know where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the extension of the app.

eg: `Google Chrome.app`

```
String script = "tell app \"Google Chrome.app\" to activate";
```